# IE edge stops rendering the page

Tags: internet-explorer

I have tested my website in all the versions of IE and everything works as expected. Although when I came to testing in IE edge I have found that everything works fine, but now and again the browser stops rendering the page half way through, literally leaving me with a visually half loaded page.

This is completely random and can happen on any page at anytime. I would say it happens around 10% of the time and another page refresh normally sorts the issue out.

The first thing I tried to do to fix it was add the following meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Although this failed to work.

I know it is difficult to find answers to a question when there is no code available, but I have literally ran out of any other options. I really do appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: There is no such thing as "IE Edge". Please be clear whether you are testing in IE in Edge rendering mode, or Microsoft Edge, the other browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `IE=Edge` to `IE=9`, it could help.

```
content="IE=9, chrome=1"
```